# PHP Trouble writing a reordering function for a 2-dimensional array of arbitrary length

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, recursion

Broadly speaking, I have a 2-dimensional array of the following format:

```
$elements = array(  0 => array('typeA', 'desc'),
                    1 => array('typeB', 'desc'),
                    2 => array('typeA', 'desc'),
                    n => array('typeC', 'desc'));
```

Where `typeX` can be 1 of 5 possibilities, and `desc` can be anything. The end goal is `$elements` sorted such that no two elements who share a `typeX` are ever adjacent. Here's my function:

```
function fixDbls($elems) {
    $final   = array();
    $singles = array();
    $doubles = array();
    $lastelem = null;
    foreach($elems as $elem) {
        if(!$lastelem) { // set this the first time through
            $lastelem = $elem[0];
            $singles[] = $elem;
        } else { //otherwise, sort!
            if($lastelem == $elem[0]) {
                $doubles[] = $elem;
            } else {
                $singles[] = $elem;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($doubles) {
            // I suspect this is where it all goes wrong, I am awful at recursion!
        $final = fixDbls(array_merge($singles, $doubles));
    } else {
        $final = $singles;
    }

    return $final;
}
```

If anyone can help me understand why this doesn't work (not just the code, but, where I've made a false assumption or where my thinking about this problem betrayed me—helps makes this more generally useful to the public!) I'd be ever, ever so appreciative.

Comment: For starters, can you ensure your data allows that kind of result? I mean, how do you make sure the input array doesn't have, for instance every element of the same typeX?

Comment: Well pointed out; yeah, this is for use in cognitive psychology, the inputs are known/controlled for. We're just constrained by a piece of third party software in terms of how the data is collected & I've been tasked with scripting its conversion to our desired format. :|

Comment: This seems like an algorythmical rather than a programming problem. It might help thinking about it in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring terms, having each type as a color and each element as a node. In your problem each node can be connected to at most 2 others, perhaps the available algorithms for these kind of problems can give you a hint. For the particulars of this issue, in order for the solution to exist, there must be at least enough elements to put between the most frequent type. I tried an alogithm of my own, but it didn't work, sorry :(

Comment: "Sort" is the wrong word here - it implies ordering and sequence. "Arrange" is better.

Comment: Agreed, change implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking your problem over and I think I came up with a solution. Here's the

```
code:

<?php

function print_array( $s, $a )
{
    echo $s.': { ';
    foreach ( $a as $k => $aa ) {
        echo $k.' => ';
        if ( is_array($aa) ) {
            echo '{ '.implode( ', ', $aa ).' }, ';
        } else {
            echo $aa.', ';
        }
    }
    echo '}'.PHP_EOL;
}

function search_array( array $a, $k )
{
    $found = false;
    foreach ( $a as $kk => $aa ) {
        if ( $aa[0] == $k ) {
            $found = $kk;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $found;
}

$input = array(  
        array('typeA', 'desc'),
            array('typeB', 'desc'),
                array('typeA', 'desc'),
                array('typeC', 'desc')
);

print_array( 'Initial input', $input );
$frequencies = array();

foreach ( $input as $e ) {
    $frequencies[ $e[0] ] = array_key_exists( $e[0], $frequencies ) ? $frequencies[ $e[0] ] + 1 : 1;
}

arsort($frequencies);

print_array( 'Frequencies', $frequencies );
$tail = array_slice( $frequencies, 1 );
$maxFreq = current( $frequencies ); 
$orderedElems = array_keys( $frequencies );
$mostFreq = current( $orderedElems );

echo 'The most frecuent element is "'.$mostFreq.'"'.PHP_EOL;

if ( array_sum( $tail ) < $maxFreq - 1 ) {
    die ('There\'s No possible solution'.PHP_EOL);
}

$ouput = array();

for ( $i = 0; $i < $maxFreq; $i++ ) {
    $k = search_array( $input, $mostFreq);
    $output[] = $input[ $k ];
    unset( $input[ $k ] );
}

print_array( 'Input after removing "'.$mostFreq.'"', $input );

echo '-----'.PHP_EOL;
print_array( 'Before process, output', $output );

foreach ( $tail as $e => $f ) {
    $i = 1;
    echo 'Elem to place: "'.$e.'" ('.$f.' times)'.PHP_EOL;
    while ( ( $k = search_array( $input, $e ) ) !== false ) {
        echo '$i: '.$i.PHP_EOL;
        $begin = array_slice( $output, 0, $i );
        print_array( 'Begin', $begin );
        $end = array_slice( $output, $i );
        print_array( 'End', $end );
        $output = array_merge( $begin, array( $input[$k] ), $end );
        print_array( 'Output', $output );
        $i+=2;
        unset( $input[$k] );
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}

print_array( 'Final output', $output );
```

This time I just tried the example you put in the question. The end result was:

```
Final output: { 0 => { typeA, desc }, 1 => { typeB, desc }, 2 => { typeC, desc }, 3 => { typeA, desc }, }
```

I hope this version suits your needs.

Comment: Well, first of all, thanks for the effort. But, this doesn't at all address my question, which is not how to order the elements of an array, but rather, how to order them by the  first index of each element's array. If you still want to answer this, I'd re-read my question, but thanks anyway.

Comment: I tried a simplified scenario in order to test the idea. Let me give another piece of code which deals with the ordering based on a two dimensional array (I hope this time I get it right :)

Answer (score 0):

I made it a function now. This should work, the best.

```
$elements = array(0 => array('typeA', 'desc'), 1 => array('typeA', 'desc'), 2 => array('typeB', 'desc'), 3 => array('typeC', 'desc'), 4 => array('typeC', 'desc'), 5 => array('typeB', 'desc'), 6 => array('typeB', 'desc'), 7 => array('typeD', 'desc'), 8 => array('typeD', 'desc'), 9 => array('typeA', 'desc'), 10 => array('typeA', 'desc'));
function sortDeep($ary){
  foreach($ary as $a){
    foreach($a as $i => $v){
      if($i === 0)$typesArray[] = $v;
    }
  }
  function notNextTo($a, $b){
    if($a === $b){
      return 1;
    }
    else{
      return 0;
    }
  }
  uasort($typesArray, 'notNextTo'); $ak = array_keys($typesArray);
  foreach($ary as $i => $v){
    $sorted[$i] = $ary[$ak[$i]];
  }
  return $sorted;
}
print_r(sortDeep($elements));
```

Comment: I admit that this script is pretty dense and I'm not entirely sure I follow it, but I gathered that `$notNextTo = $element[$i][0]` should in fact read `$elements`  (with an 's'). In either case, neither of these worked for me, both output the elements in a different order than that in which they entered but with plenty of duplicates. :(

Comment: Tried your updated version. Still no luck; the output is quite a mess, usually several duplicate items followed by the creation of arrays where strings once were (ie. $element[$i][0] (which is the comparison index) becomes an array at some point and all elements at that depth thereafter are also replaced with arrays. Thanks, again, though.